# Can SDL work with pure C?

Tags: c, sdl

How do I setup SDL to work in C? 
What I mean is without classes, in pure C. I have seen few projects in C that use SDL, but when I try to set it up or download, there is only C++ version. Could you please guide me how to install SDL for C in Mac (Xcode) or Windows environment?

Edit: I know that SDL is written in C, but it doesn't make it C library. First tutorial (and all others I have checked heavily use classes. First one from tutorial section on the site, uses class code on second page. http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics

LazyFoo tutorials although old, they use c++ too.

Could you link me to a tutorial that uses C?

Comment: SDL _is_ a pure C library. If you look at the [introduction](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/toc.html), for example, there are no C++ examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL is a C library, so yes, you can use it with 'pure C'.

Comment: Yes, but all the examples and tutorials use C++.

Comment: And if you look at them, all SDL calls are just (C) function calls.

Answer (score 3):

SDL is a C library with a C API (any many others). There are many [demos](http://www.libsdl.org/demos.php) online.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this tutorial](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials) - look under "General" on page for [setting-up dev-environment](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aSetup)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in learning SDL but want all of your code to be in `pure C` then you just translate the C++ concepts in LazyFoo's tutorials into C equivalents. To answer your question: Yes, you can write code using SDL without using C++. But if you're looking at other people's code in C++ and you want C you're going to have to do a little work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vala/Genie is fast like c and easy like python. See here:
[Manual de Genie-Valac](http://www.manualgenie.blogspot.com)!